# How to draw a roofline chart in latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, diagrams

I'm trying to find some examples of roofline charts in latex, but unfortunately I couldn't find anything that replicates this example below.

Roofline chart:

[image]

Code I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmode=log,
    ymode=log,
    xlabel={Operational Intensity (FLOPS/Byte)},
    ylabel={Performance (FLOPS)},
    grid=major,
    xmin=0.01, xmax=100,
    ymin=1, ymax=1000,
    legend pos=north west,
]

% L1 Bandwidth Roofline
\addplot[name path=global, domain=0.01:1, red, thick] {x*1000} node[pos=0.6,anchor=south east] {L1 Bandwidth};
% L2 Bandwidth Roofline
\addplot[name path=l2, domain=0.01:2, blue, thick] {x*500} node[pos=0.5,anchor=south east] {L2 Bandwidth};
% L3 Bandwidth Roofline
\addplot[name path=l3, domain=0.01:10, green, thick] {x*200} node[pos=0.3,anchor=south east] {L3 Bandwidth};
% DRAM Bandwidth Roofline
\addplot[name path=dram, domain=0.01:100, orange, thick] {x*50} node[pos=0.1,anchor=south east] {DRAM Bandwidth};

% Compute Bound Roofline
\addplot[name path=compute, domain=1:100, black, thick] {100} node[pos=0.5,anchor=south] {Compute Bound};

% Shading under rooflines
\addplot[green!30] fill between[of=l3 and compute, soft clip={domain=0.01:10}];
\addplot[blue!30] fill between[of=l2 and l3, soft clip={domain=0.01:2}];
\addplot[red!30] fill between[of=global and l2, soft clip={domain=0.01:1}];
\addplot[orange!30] fill between[of=dram and global, soft clip={domain=0.01:100}];

% Example Kernel Performance Point
\addplot[mark=*, mark options={fill=black}, mark size=3pt] coordinates {(1,50)} node[anchor=south west] {Kernel A};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: what you try? Where you stuck? This can be easy to draw using `pgfplots`. See package documentation for examples.

Comment: Sure, I can update my question.

Comment: I see several superficial differences between the two images, but I'm not sure how hard any of those changes would be.  Could you elaborate on what differences you're having trouble with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do it in plain-`Tikz`.

Remarks:

1. This diagram doesn't scale, as it's `in absolute coordinates`. I perceive your sketch as a 15cm x 4.5cm rectangle. All positions are estimated.
2. Code starts with a series of `style-statements`: color-related, for the roof-lines, data points and their labels.
3. As a last step during development I drew the `shaded area`. For this purpose it was useful, to `refactor some coordinates`, i.e. state them in the beginning, and replace them later in code whenever used. To be "painted over", it had to be first.
4. Grid and frame are no big deal.
5. `Labels` use two `\foreach` loops. `\i` is used to further calculate positions for placement. For the y-axis the nodes have to be `anchor=east`, so they look like being ragged right. I.e. the coordinate relates to the right middle side, rather than the nodes center.
6. The `roof lines` put the dashed verticals first. The "curves" are just a few strokes.
7. `Data points` use a node with a circle as shape and empty text. This way the radius is set via minimum node dimensions.
8. The `labels` relate to those data points positions, like `(A)`, but are shifted in polar coordinates. They use `rounded corners`. Directly after that a line is put, using polar coordinates for the anchor points. E.g. `(AL.90)` would be `(AL.north)`, while (AL.60) anchors a bit more to the right.
9. Finally, the peak-note and axes text are put.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    % ~~~ colors ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    grl/.style={gray!40},
    ctl/.style={teal!50},
    cbl/.style={fill=teal!15!blue!5,draw=none},
    % ~~~ roof lines ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    r1/.style={line width=1.5pt},
    r2/.style={line width=1.5pt,ctl},
    dev/.style={sloped,above,pos=.1,text=black},
    l1/.style={dashed,line width=1.3pt},
    l2/.style={l1,ctl},
    % ~~~ data points and labels ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    dp/.style={circle,fill=teal!60,draw=black},
    lbl/.style={fill=white,rounded corners,draw},
    shft/.style={shift=(203:8mm)},
    shftu/.style={shift=(130:7mm)},
 ]
    % ~~~ some coordinates from refactoring, for the shaded area ~~~~~~~
    \coordinate (Z) at  (6,4.2);    
    \coordinate (ZZ) at (0,1.8);    
    \coordinate (Y) at  (6,0);  
    \coordinate (X) at  (10.2,4.2); 
    \coordinate (W) at  (10.2,0);   
    
    % ~~~ shaded area ~~~~~~~~
    \draw[cbl] (ZZ) -- (Z) -- (X) -- (W) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
    
    % ~~~ grid and frame ~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[grl]              (0,0) grid[xstep=5cm] ( 15,4.5);
    \draw[line width=1.0pt] (0,0) rectangle (15,4.5);
    
    % ~~~ labels ~~~~~~~~~~~
    \foreach \x [count=\i] in {0.01, 0.1, 1, 10}
        \node at (\i*5 - 5, -.3) {\x};
                
    \foreach \y [count=\i] in {0.3, 1, 3, 10, 30}
        \node[anchor=east] at (-0.3, \i-1) {\y};
        
    % ~~~ roofs and lines ~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[l1] (Z) -- (Y);       % refactored coordinates, see above
    \draw[l2] (X) -- (W);
    \draw[r1] (ZZ) -- node[dev] {L3} (Z) -- (15,4.2);
    \draw[r2] (0,.1) -- node[dev] {DRAM} (X);
    
    % ~~~ data points and labels ~~~~~~~~~
    \node[dp] (A) at (9.8,2.7) {};
    \node[dp] (B) at (7.5,3.3) {};
    \node[dp] (C) at (6.5,2) {};
    \node[dp] (D) at (6.2,0.3) {};
    
    \node[lbl] (AL) at ([shft]A) {LOG}; \draw (AL.60) -- (A);
    \node[lbl] (BL) at ([shft]B) {KME}; \draw (BL.60) -- (B);
    \node[lbl] (CL) at ([shft]C) {LIN}; \draw (CL.60) -- (C);
    \node[lbl] (DL) at ([shftu]D) {DTR}; \draw (DL.300) -- (D);
    
    % ~~~ peak note ~~~
    \node[anchor=west] at (10.3,3.9) {Peak compute performance};
    
    % ~~~ axes ~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node at (7.5,-1) {Arithmetic Intensity (OP/B)};
    \node[rotate=90] at (-1.3,2.1) {Performance (GOPS)};
 
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```