How to recreate "old style" graphs
I am still a beginner in LaTeX and would like to know if it is possible to reproduce this type of graph identically (same font, same line thickness, etc.). If this is indeed possible, I would love to learn how to do it.

KR, W-58.

Welcome. // Please take courage to post code of your best trial, where we can better learn about your roadblocks. // For drawing the axis see e.g. here (coordinate system) https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/732874/245790 . This one https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239874/tikz-pgfplots-how-can-i-generate-a-figure-like-this-one/724999#724999 shows many ways to scribble lines. // This one also tries ragged lines: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325301/plot-with-ragged-lines?noredirect=1&lq=1 . // In general, follow links at the right under "Related".

with lualatex you can use any font your system has installed, I can't tell exactly what font that is but any  heavyish sans serif would give a similar look

Okok, I will study that and repost.

For a start I'd try the Latex standard sans serif font (this would allow using pdflatex). Perhaps it's already close enough. Unless you reproduce an old book or so, visual consistency may be more impartant than fancyness ;-)

Here's also a nice approach for ragged lines: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199570/245790 . // Here you can see drawing lines and placing text/labels https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703564/245790

The font looks like some kind of Helvetica, the letters below (Fig. 22.7) look like Times. So nothing really special here. If you want the same “old” effect, create the thing with LaTeX, and then print and scan it at least twice …

Edit v2 : removing useless packages, removing duplicate tznode.
Here is an example of what you could get (the tzplot package is very useful for economic figures) :
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tzplot}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\irregularline}{%
  O     {2mm}   % Amplitude of irregularity. Optional. Default value = 2mm
  m             % First point
  m             % Second point
  D   <> {20}   % Number of peaks. Optional. Default value = 20
}{{%
  \coordinate (old) at #2;
  \foreach \i in {1,2,...,#4}{
    \draw (old) -- ($ ($#2!\i/(#4+1)!#3$) + (0,#1*rand) $) coordinate (old);
  }
  \draw (old) -- #3;
}}

% Start the document
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\bfseries\sffamily\large\scshape, ultra thick]

%Draxing your axes
\tzaxes [-]% Style of your axis
(0,0)% Start coordinates
(10,7)% End coordinates
{X}% Legend of the X-axis
{Y}% Legend of Y-axis
[l]% Position of Y-axis ("a" by default)
\tznode (0,0) {O} [l] % Respectively : coordinates, label name and position of the origin label

% Writing your axes label
\tznode[rotate=90](-0.5,4){Rate of exchange}[a]% Write "Rate or exchange" in position (-0.5,4) rotated 90° counterclockwise with text above.
\tznode(5,-0.5){Amount of foreign exchange}[b]% Write "Amount of foreign exchange" in position (5,-0.5) with text below.

% Drawing your supply curves
\def\supply{0.7*\x+1}% Define your supply curve formula
\tzfn\supply[1:8]{$\text{S}$}[r]% Draw your curve between 1-8 and add a label "S" to the right [r]
\tzfn"supply1"{\supply-1}[1.5:8.5]{$\text{S}_\text{1}$}[r]%Draw your curve between 1.5-8.5 and add a label "S_1" to the right [r]

% Drawing your demand curves
\def\demand{-0.7*\x+6.5} % Define your demand curve formula
\tzfn\demand[1:8]{$\text{D}$}[r]%Draw your curve between 1-8 and add a label "D" to the right [r]
\tzfn"demand1"{\demand+1}[1.5:8.5]{$\text{D}_\text{1}$}[r]%Draw your curve between 1.5-8.5 and add a label "D_1" to the right [r]

% Drawing the Demand-Supply junction point
\tzXpoint*{demand}{supply}(DS)%Find the point where the supply and demand curve intersect and call it "DS"
\tzproj[dashed](DS){Q}{R}% Draw the DS intersection and add Q as x-point label and R as y-point label

% Drawing irregularlines
\irregularline[2pt]{(0.3,5)}{(2.7,5.5)}<24>
\irregularline[2pt]{(2.7,5.5)}{(5,5)}<23>
\irregularline[2pt]{(5,5)}{(10,5.3)}<50>
\tznode(10,5){Commodity\\export\\point}[align=center, ar]

\irregularline[2pt]{(0.3,4)}{(3.3,4.5)}<17>
\irregularline[2pt]{(3.3,4.5)}{(5.2,3.5)}<10>
\irregularline[2pt]{(5.2,3.5)}{(10,3.6)}<70>
\tznode(10,3.6){Purchasing\\Power parity}[align=center, r]

\irregularline[3pt]{(0.3,0.5)}{(10,0.6)}<70>
\tznode(10,0.6){Commodity\\Import\\Point}[align=center, r]

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


